# How do I launch an app confined into its own virtual desktop?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, desktop

I am running macOS 10.12 Sierra and I have an app which doesn't behave properly especially with multiple screens. Thus, I want to confine it into its own virtual desktop. The result I'm looking for is similar to what Wine can do for Windows programs:

[image: Wine virtual desktop]

(Picture from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1383144))

*How can I do that?*

On Linux I could do it by running a separate login session via VNC to my own machine (`127.0.0.1`) but cannot get this idea to work on macOS. After enabling VNC in the *System Preferences*, the *Screen Sharing* client says I cannot control my own desktop.

Is there any way I can constrain an app into its own virtual desktop with a single screen and fixed resolution? I'd like to avoid running a virtual machine just for this task.

Comment: In what way is what you're looking for different from a virtual machine?

Comment: @timothymh I'm asking how to merely run a separate login session using the same OS on the same host. At most I may need to run a different display server or just an app that "locks" the window of my app. A VM would require running a totally different instance of the OS, with a separate kernel, separate login account, a separate root file system and different hardware (real vs virtual). I don't see how these things are comparable at all.

Comment: Ah, sorry, your use of the phrase "virtual desktop" instead of "login session" confused me.

Comment: @timothymh it is a "desktop" in the sense used also by Wine or VNC, i.e. the app must believe it is placed in a single screen of size e.g. 1024x768 and act accordingly. Thanks for pointing out a possible ambiguity, though.